# How can I use a NSNumber from a different class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to simple get a `NSNumber` from a different class.

What I have in my Class2.h:

```
#import "Class1.h"

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSNumber *rowTodelete;
```

This is how my Class2.m looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.rowTodelete = 3;
}
```

In my Class1.h

```
#import "Class2.h"
```

In my Class1.m

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

Class2 *secondClass = [[Class alloc] init];

    NSNumber *newNumber = secondClass.rowToDelete;

    NSLog(@"the new number is %@",self.newNumber);
}
```

And I keep getting a `null` value. I just want to get my `NSNumber` from Class2 and assign it to new `NSNumber` in Class1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please try to be more careful when posting your code. You cannot assign a primitive to an object (`self.rowTodelete = 3`), nor can you have a class named `Class` (`[[Class alloc] init]`).

Comment: You do realise when you give a bad review it freezes the person off the site.  When all they are trying to do is learn and get better

Comment: I only left a comment, I didn't vote you up or down.

Comment: My apologies.  Just thought my question was reasonable

Comment: Your question is reasonable, but sometimes it's difficult for people to help you if the code that you post does not exhibit the behaviour that is causing you trouble.

Comment: There's some crazy down voting going on; as well as my answer below somebody has 'coincidentally' been on a rampage through my answer history down voting whatever he can find. @burrGGG there's nothing wrong with your question, it just appears a maniac has been through.

Comment: @burrGGG: You can learn from both things that Ian said. The viewDidLoad isn't going to compile for the first reason that Ian said, and the viewDidAppear isn't going to compile for the second reason that he gave.

Answer (score 2):

`Class2 *secondClass = [[Class alloc] init];` creates and instantiates a new instance of `Class`. Nobody else has ever seen that instance before. That's what `alloc` and `init` do. That class will therefore have its initial default values for all fields.

I'm not sure how much of this is patronising but to provide further information:

A class declaration like `Class` or `Class2` establishes a mould. It's the design patterns for how instances of that class will act. Each instance is a separate manufacturing from the mould.

So e.g. saying that `Class2` has an `NSNumber` property named `rowToDelete` says that every individual instance of that class will have a place with that name where it can store a number.

When you perform `alloc] init]` you manufacture a brand new instance of the class. Each instance has its own individual storage named `rowToDelete`. So the instance of `secondClass` that you manufacture in `viewDidAppear:` is (with some minor assumptions about unshown code) completely distinct, and using completely distinct storage, to that which set `self.rowToDelete`. Different instances, different storage.

Think about something like `NSMutableString`. It will be using some storage for the characters in the string. Each string should have its own storage and changes to one shouldn't affect any other. It's the same with `rowToDelete`.

If these are both view controllers and the one that picks a row is responsible for showing the one that acts on it, you'd normally push that value either at creation or during the segue depending on whether you're using segues. If it's the other way around then you'd probably want to use a delegate protocol between the two.

If you can supply more context, I can be more specific.

Comment: So is this the wrong way to go about doing this then?

Comment: @burrGGG if you want to store a property to an instance of a class and have somebody else access that property, the second person needs to access the same instance. There's not really enough context confidently to say more than that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the value in class2's `viewDidLoad`

This method is not called until the ViewController has been loaded and is about to be displayed.

I don't know the specifics of what you are trying to achieve, but you could change the superclass of class2 to NSObject for example and move the assignment to class2's `init` method. Or you could keep class2 as a viewController subclass and put the assignment in one of its init methods.